# Visual studio TEST missing from the main menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2013

After updating to visual studio 2013, update 4, the TEST option is missing from my screen, I thought Visual Studio update 5 would fix it, but it did not. "TEST" is missing from my options and I don't know why.

[image: Test option missing]

I have tried resetting the settings, it does not help, reset settings:

[image]

I cannot add test via TOOLS -> CUSTOMIZE -> COMMANDS -> ADD COMMAND, it is not there.

[image: Test missing]

Comment: What edition of Visual Studio are you working with? Have you *ever* had the TEST menu present?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, I've run tests before, I'm currently at Visual Studio 2013.5

Comment: Edition, not Version e.g. Professional, Premium, Ultimate.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but uninstalling Office Tools extension seems to have fixed it.

**Edit:** I tried to reproduce this bug, I ran the VS2013.5 update and clicked repair. The update took +5 hours, figured it got stuck. So I cancelled it, got stuck cancelling. So I ended the process. Now I started visual studio and TEST is missing, basically my visual studio installation is messed up I think.

**Edit:** Found the culprit, it was **Microsoft Intune Endpoint Protection** that was installed on my pc. It basically scanned everything and when visual studio got updated and files were written to the disk, something went wrong and corrupted my install. I turned it off by excluding `C:\*` from being scanned and ran VS2013.5 update and clicked repair. Everything is fine now.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid of something like this, VS has gone/become corrupt during the update (maybe due to cancel maybe something else). Best off not to bother ts'ing it, it's in a bad state so uninstall it, then use msicuu2 to completely get rid of any left overs, then reinstall.

Answer (score 5):

> What edition of Visual Studio are you working with? Have you ever had
>   the TEST menu present?
>
> **Yes, I've run tests before**, I'm currently
>   at Visual Studio 2013.5 - Premium flavor

@OP answered:

> I don't know why, but uninstalling Office Tools extension seems to have fixed it.

---

I wanted to provide an explanation for why Menu's can go missing. One reason for this is when you install another component for Visual Studio, like Team Foundation Client or in this case Office Tools extension. They "may" automatically select a different setting. To check if this is the problem:

In Visual Studio click Tools Menu > Import and Export Settings:

[image]

[image]

**See here how Project Management Settings is selected, that is the wrong setting if you're a Developer**.

[image]

**To see the missing developer menu's reset it back to a developer setting.**

Ref: http://blog.accentient.com/a-visual-studio-mystery-the-case-of-the-missing-menu-items/

Comment: I have visual studio 2013, not 2010, added screenshot of default settings.I tried resetting settings, it did not work, and it does not explain why I could not find TEST in add command.

Comment: Is that screenshot BEFORE you uninstalled Office Extensions?

Comment: No, after but TEST is missing again, check my solution.

Comment: It might be good to reinstall The Office Extensions and see if the Test menu disappears again so we can confirm its not settings and try other ts'ing techniques

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in VS 2015 Update 2 Community and the culprit apparently was AppInsights extension (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11653).  To provide some detail:

- Noticed test menu missing in existing solution where I previously ran tests
- Made a blank test project, still no test menu
- closed vs and reopened.  Still not test menu
- Got error referencing C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml
- Last error in there was NullReferenceException in CodeLensIndicatorService
- Googling that found link above, tieing to this add-in.
- disabling it fixed the issue and test menu not appears and I can run tests.

Forgive me if I complain a bit, but if any VS team is reading: Under no circumstances should an add-in failing cause a built-in menu to not appear.  As much as this is a bug caused by the the various add-ins, it is also a flaw in VS IMO- and one that is not trivial for end-users to connect the dots on.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the settings (settings have menu items configuration also) for your visual studio may have issue. Either you can try reset. Only in case that doesn't work you can always customize your menu item. so 
Tool -> Customize (by default standard should be selected)

select commands tab and then menu bar option. You can see options to add commands. Under that you can select test so make testing option visible.

Also for testing test case, you can always right click on class and run it.

Hi Please try to reset all setting 
http://blog.accentient.com/a-visual-studio-mystery-the-case-of-the-missing-menu-items/

If not then there is workaround to add your setting
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/09/11/visual-studio-2012-where-is-the-test-toolbar-couldn-t-find-it-anywhere.aspx

After doing close visual studio instances and reopen it.

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: hope its more elaborate now