# Visual Studio 2022 has no 'Test' menu

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2022

I've recently had to reset my Windows installation and re-install all my applications.

Now I've re-installed Visual Studio 2022, I seem to have lost the "Tests" menu, and the "View" menu doesn't contain any mention of the Test Explorer, which I use extensively.

Can anyone help with what I can do to get these back? I've checked all my settings in the Visual Studio installer and can't see anything test-related in there except for "Test Adapter for Google Test" (which I have installed) and "Test Adapter for Boost.Test" (which I don't use, so is unchecked - I did try installing this to see if it made any difference, but it didn't).

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this old problem might help to find the right direction? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604119/visual-studio-test-missing-from-the-main-menu

Comment: Hi @suvidu, thanks for the link. I managed to fix the problem by uninstalling and re-installing Visual Studio (although not sure why; I guess I must have made a slightly different selection of components to install). Your link might contain some useful ideas if I need to try again though...